# What anchors to use for UITextView?

Tags: swift

If I set the leading/trailing, top/bottom anchors, my UITextView appears; if I set leading/trailing, top anchor + height, then it appears too. But if I leave one anchor out, my UITextView doesn't appear at all. Why is this? I'd assume it would spill out? For example, if I didn't specify a bottom anchor, I'd assume it would overflow to the bottom. But I don't think it appears at all - what exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. You must specify, for every view, all four aspects:

- horizontal position
- vertical position
- horizontal size
- vertical size

That's all there is to it. If you omit one of those, then your specifications are incomplete ("ambiguous") and the view is, if you're lucky, not drawn.

Some view types, such as a UILabel or a UIButton or a UIImageView, supply one or both of the size aspects internally based on their contents. So for those view types you might be able to omit specifying that aspect yourself.  But a UITextView is not one of those; it's all entirely up to you.